# trunk serve not hot reloading?

Tags: rust, webassembly, hot-reload, yew, trunk-rs

I am following along a walkthrough on how to use WebAssembly with Rust to build a [simple web page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-O9QkrlfYw).They mention that hosting the website locally using trunk serve should provide hot reloading where if I make changes to my code, I should see those changes have an effect on the website, but I am not.

I followed the video exactly so I don't know what I'm missing.

I have tried a few commands:

1. `trunk serve`
2. `trunk serve --watch .` No different from the first.
3. `cargo watch -c -- trunk serve` Which I found [here](https://github.com/thedodd/trunk/issues/232). Constantly reloads (without making changes to the source code) and I cannot connect.

When I open the web page (127.0.0.1:8080) and make a change to my html, no changes are shown on the web page (even after refreshing.) In order to see the changes, I have to `CTRL+C` out of the server and boot it back up (which is tedious and obnoxious.)

Comment: I have since moved to [leptos](https://github.com/leptos-rs/start), which has a `cargo leptos watch` that *does* successfully hot reload. I guess I'm going that route instead...

Answer (score 4):

As a temporary solution I have found using this command works:
`cargo watch -w .\src\  -s "trunk serve"`

Comment: before using this command , you should add ``cargo-watch`` with this ```cargo install cargo-watch```